# MongoDB positional $ (update) operator wrong

Tags: mongodb

According to the [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) the $ operator can be used to update content into an embedded list which matches the query document. My example is a bit more complex than the one in the documentation:

```js
db.item.insert({
    "_id" : ObjectId("5398786591846667374b8f7c"),
    "outputs" : [ 
        {
            "action" : "VIDEO",
            "portalType" : "FACEBOOK",
            "status" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "portalType" : "YOUTUBE",
            "action" : "VIDEO",
            "status" : 1
        }
    ]
})
```

And now I perform the following query:

```js
db.item.update(
{ _id: ObjectId('5398786591846667374b8f7c'),
    "outputs.portalType": "YOUTUBE",
    "outputs.action": "VIDEO" },
{ $set: { "outputs.$.status": NumberInt(99)}})
```

Surprisingly, the result is that the first element of the outputs array is modified (the one with portalType=FACEBOOK), which is certainly wrong according to my query: "outputs which contains action=VIDEO **and** portalType=YOUTUBE".

http://s16.postimg.org/dyf4fmi6d/Untitled.png

---

**EDIT:** 
To match multiple criterias inside an array and be sure all are matching, **$elemMatch** should be used in the query part of the update command, like suggested by **Neil Lunn**

Comment: Umm. You have a different ObjectId value in your update than the sample. I think you will find that this actually works. Sorry to burst your bubble on bug hunt.

Comment: Thanks. That was just a typo, and the error persists ;)

Comment: Nope. I just even ran that myself. Updates the correct array member. You have not found a bug.

Comment: Can you please provide the two commands you used to make it run properly? As long as the version of mongoDB?

I use exactly those two commands from my first post in the mongo, one after another and the result is not the desired.

Answer (score 0):

This does actually work as designed.

Here is the data:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5398786591846667374b8f7c"),
    "outputs" : [
            {
                    "action" : "VIDEO",
                    "portalType" : "FACEBOOK",
                    "status" : 1
            },
            {
                    "portalType" : "YOUTUBE",
                    "action" : "VIDEO",
                    "status" : 1
            }
    ]
}
```

Here is the update:

```js
db.item.update(
   { 
        "_id": ObjectId("5398786591846667374b8f7c"),
        "outputs.portalType": "YOUTUBE",
        "outputs.action": "VIDEO"
   }, 
   { "$set": { "outputs.$.status": NumberInt(99) }}
)
```

Here is the result:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5398786591846667374b8f7c"),
    "outputs" : [
            {
                    "action" : "VIDEO",
                    "portalType" : "FACEBOOK",
                    "status" : 1
            },
            {
                    "portalType" : "YOUTUBE",
                    "action" : "VIDEO",
                    "status" : 99
            }
    ]
}
```

Perhaps this is your problem as your conditions might not be doing as you expect them to:

```js
db.item.update(
   { 
        "_id": ObjectId("5398786591846667374b8f7c"),
        "outputs": { 
            "$elemMatch": {
                "portalType": "YOUTUBE",
                "action": "VIDEO" 
            }
        }
   }, 
   { "$set": { "outputs.$.status": NumberInt(99) }}
)
```

So the [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) makes sure **both** conditions are present within the array item, where as the previous form could possibly match other members of the array. The match is only on the "document" as a whole otherwise.

So here is the [try.mongodb.org](http://try.mongodb.org/) output:
[image]

Noting the last line of the update statement and the modified document.

Comment: I tested your code in http://try.mongodb.org/ and it works when the query update is done in that precise order. If the order is as follows: `"_id": ObjectId("5398786591846667374b8f7c"), "outputs.action": "VIDEO", "outputs.portalType": "YOUTUBE"` then the wrong one is modified. try it yourself.

Comment: @DidacMontero Dude What do you think I just posted. Of course I know this works. Geez. Check my profile around here. It is not as if I do not know what I am talking about.

Comment: @DidacMontero You seem to be complaining that the online demo does not understand `NumberInt`. That is just a website. Real life MongoDB instances work as designed.

Comment: I don't mind NumberInt doesn't work there and that's not the issue. The update query (not the one with elemMatch) doesn't make sure both conditions are present, as far as I can see, because when I run the command I see different results if the part related with the query is `"_id": ObjectId("5398786591846667374b8f7c"), "outputs.action": "VIDEO", "outputs.portalType": "YOUTUBE"` or `"_id": ObjectId("5398786591846667374b8f7c"), "outputs.portalType": "YOUTUBE","outputs.action": "VIDEO"`

Comment: @DidacMontero Please drop the argumentative tone and actually look. There is even a screenshot there for what you are trying to reproduce. There is no bug or problem. The statement works as it should and does.

Comment: I do appreciate your collaboration and It isn't my intention to use any pejorative tone. What I am doing wrong, according to this screenshot (from try.mongodb.org): http://s16.postimg.org/dyf4fmi6d/Untitled.png

Comment: @DidacMontero What you are doing wrong is you didn't read all of the answer posted as I asked you to. Look at the last mention there for `$elemMatch` and the explaination of the difference between the query you are sending. Your other data in the first element is the match. The positional operator always returns the first match as you could also read from the link to the documentation that was provided.

Comment: I already read it before, as you can see in some of my previous comments. Then I will use elemMatch instead. I understood from the documentation that it will return the first match from all the query, and the query has an and operator (implicit). But I see that is not like that. Thanks for your time.